# Mbed OS NFCController: detect targets

Tags: nfc, mbed

I need to use the Mbed OS features to use my DISCO-L475VG-IOT01A in order to synchronously wait until an NFC target (I plan to use a simple tag I have) is placed near it, and to do something whenever that happens.

It looks like the `NFCController` class and its [`Delegate`](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.12/mbed-os-api-doxy/structmbed_1_1nfc_1_1_n_f_c_controller_1_1_delegate.html#ad9e19cf137a35ff958b187ab8437c160) have the stuff I need, in particular the `virtual void on_nfc_initiator_discovered` method.

However, I've found these NFC Examples:
https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-nfc
https://os.mbed.com/teams/ST/code/HelloWorld_Async_M24SR/graph/

and they don't really show anything about how to use the class (the GitHub one maybe does but it's all really tangled in included files and I can't really get anything useful out of it. Furthermore they all use the board as a target, while I need to use it as an initiator (the [start_discovery](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.12/mbed-os-api-doxy/classmbed_1_1nfc_1_1_n_f_c_controller.html#a653e35089411ee2fa9af69fbc3fecbc6) method of the `NFCController` class looks like what I need). Does anyone know of better, more esplicative examples about the stuff I need? Or could anyone please tell me how to combine the `M24SR` driver class with the `NFCController` class to achieve what I need?